# How to test for a named item in an item frame? (1.16.1)

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a 7x7 jigsaw puzzle. I want to know how I can use `/execute` (or a different command) to check for a filled map named `Map#26` in an item frame at coordinates (-26, 74 -100).

Edit: Okay so, I changed locations.

```
execute if entity @e[type=minecraft:item_frame,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:filled_map"}}] run say jeff
```

The command above executes if there is a filled map in an item frame anywhere. Once there is a map in an item frame it will say `jeff.`

What I am trying to figure out is a command that executes if there is a named filled map in an item frame at a specific item frame. Once there is a map in that item frame the command will say `joe.`"

For an example

`execute` if there is an item frame with a filled map named `Map#24` at `-26, 74, -100` run say `joe.`

Edit: Some success has been made with this command.

```
execute if entity @e[type=minecraft:item_frame,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:filled_map",tag:{display:{Name:'{"text":"Map#24"}'}}}}] run say jeff
```

The command above says `jeff` if there is a map named `Map#24` in an item frame. The thing is, that item frame can be anywhere. So far, the only what I have tried is this command:

```
execute if entity @e[x=-39.5,y=63.5,z=21.96875,type=minecraft:item_frame,nbt={Item:{id:"minecraft:filled_map",tag:{display:{Name:'{"text":"Map#24"}'}}}}] run say jeff
```

But this command didn't work for a specific location. Please help, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Update

As Minecraft commands have evolved, the performance impacts of the commands we run has become not insignificant. This answer before suggested to use the NBT tags `TileX`, `TileY`, and `TileZ`, but this is discouraged because NBT checks are heavy on performance.

The best way to detect an item frame in a certain position is to use the `dx`, `dy`, and `dz` selector arguments to create a 1×1×1 "selection cube" to find the item frame:

```
@e[type=item_frame,x=-40,y=63,z=21,dx=0,dy=0,dz=0]
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this really helped me. For anyone wondering what the final command looks like, here you go: `execute if entity @e[type=minecraft:item_frame,nbt={TileY:63,TileX:-40,TileZ:21,Item:{id:"minecraft:filled_map",tag:{display:{Name:'{"text":"Map#24"}'}}}}] run say jeff`